# Fit a block to its content, but keep its block abilities

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to have a series of blocks to fit to their respective content, yet to each stay on their row:

```
+------------------------+
|        +--------------+|
|        | Some Content ||
|        +--------------+|
|  +--------------------+|
|  | Some Other Content ||
|  +--------------------+|
|               +-------+|
|               | Small ||
|               +-------+|
|               +-------+|
|               | Small ||
|               +-------+|
+------------------------+
```

The only ideas I could find work on `inline-block`, `float` or `position: absolute;`, and all of them would put the two "Small" blocks on the same row...

Any idea on how I could achieve that?

My HTML is really basic. It looks like this (but is open to suggestions):

```
<div class="container">
    <div>Some Content</div>
    <div>Some Other Content</div>
    <div>Small</div>
    <div>Small</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know if it's you doing the serial downvoting, but most of the answers you're getting are viable, given the information you provided. If they're not the answer you're looking for, then hold out for something better and maybe provide more details. But downvoting an answer means that it is either incorrect or inapplicable to your question.

Comment: What is the end goal? Is it feasible to use `<span>`s for the child blocks, but wrap them in `<p>`s or `<div>`s? Having some semantic context for the theoretical markup would be helpful.

Comment: @Superstringcheese as you can see, I don't even have enough rep to up/down vote anyone. And yes, they all are viable :)
@Adrian I use it for a notification stack. Each `<div>` would be a notification. Yes, `<span>` would be ok. But the `clear` definitely worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `float:right` and `clear:right`:

```
.container div
{
    float:right;
    clear:right;
}
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/88uVs/1*

Comment: Right: clear! I knew I had forgotten somthing really simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
.container div {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VzT6P/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
.container div{
   float:right;
   clear:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

actually you have the option float that works really well if you clear them.
 Inline-block will not stack on each others and you cannot clear them from each others, unless you float them, so display display:).

But sometimes and for some reason, you don't ant to use float.
So you might be looking for block element that will stack on top of each other , and wrap their inline-content/box content undersized.

Table or display:table have exactly this ability and it replys to your question:

> **Fit a block to its content, but keep its block abilities.**

But if you float them , what's the point ?

You can use direction to have them go right instead left; then reset direction inside. (like you do with text-align, font-size, float, line-height or any other rules.)

The CSS i'm talking about : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/eHIaJ

```
    /* direction + table */
.direction.rtl {direction:ltr;}
    .direction div {direction:ltr;
                    display:table;
                    padding:0.25em;
    }
    /* float + clear */
.float.right div { 
  float:right;
  clear:right;
}
```

You have your solution, but i think it can be usefull to know that there's other way that works since (almost) ever . (almost = display:table not avalaible before IE8)
Cheers

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use clear: right on all "rows".

So for instance:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="medium right clear">block 1</div>
    <div class="large right clear">block 2</div>
    <div class="small right clear">block 3</div>
    <div class="small right clear">block 4</div>
</div>
```

CSS required:

```
.right { float: right; }
.clear { clear: both; }
.medium, .large, .small { /*some markup for your blocks*/ }
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tive/MFrBs/

Answer (score -1):

Give `clear:right` to all the divs. That should solve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

What you're looking for is this:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/5ypj4v4s

```
.container div {
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto; /* to align right */
}
```